# Is it a good idea to prefer NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 over NSNumberFormatterBehaviorDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I wonder if it would be more secure to rely on a NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4 instead of default, because default may change arbitrary some day in future, and suddenly the app looks ugly. Or am I wrong with that?

Answer (score 16):

On OS X, the two operation modes owe their history to the introduction in 10.4 of more useful behaviour based on standard open source libraries. For the purposes of binary compatibility, if you don't otherwise do anything then NSNumberFormatters are created with pre-10.4 behaviour.

iOS postdates the launch of OS X 10.4, so only the 10.4 behaviour is implemented and is the new default. With no legacy apps, there is no reason for pre-10.4 behaviour ever to be implemented.

Based on the approach taken on the desktop — specifically that the change was designed explicitly not to break backwards compatibility — I'd conclude that there's no benefit to stating that you want 10.4 rather than default behaviour.

Comment: You're probably doing great as a programmer, and a legal writer would probably suite you just as well.

Comment: If anyone's wondering what the difference is between 10.0 and 10.4, I think it might have something to do with these properties: [NSNumberFormatter.attributedStringForNil](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1416184-attributedstringfornil?language=objc) and [thousandSeparator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1412771-thousandseparator?language=objc) but I haven't been able to draw any broader conclusions than that from the official documentation.